# i want keyname in my jsp method

Tags: angularjs

```
$rootScope.masterLoad=function(keyName){


       console.log("inside masterLoad method!");                   
       var param = $.param({
              data:angular.toJson({"keyName":keyName})
            });
        var handlerSuccess=function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.form = response;
            /*if(response.status=="success")
              {
                  var result=JSON.parse(response.data);
                  var len = result.length;
                  for (var i = 0;  i < len; i++) {
                      if(result[i].status=="success")
                          alert("Data save successfully");
                    }

              }else{
                  alert(response.message);
              }*/
            //console.log(masterData);
            };
            saveFetchFactory.loadMaster(param).success(handlerSuccess);

   };
```

I want they keyname in function in my jsp method. how can i pass?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the guides on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically on [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No java in here..